# how to use marshmallow in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android studio and i want to use `Marshmallow` API and `AppCompatActivity`. When I created a new project the `build.gradle` contained the below lines but I receive error at R class which says `not a symbol`.

Please let me know how to correct the `build.gradle` to get the App work.

**gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.com.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: post error message you got while building gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on **Build->Clean Project** and that will perform a gradle clean

Comment: should i change any value in the posted gradle file

Comment: R is a generated class so Clean is not enough. You want Rebuild.

Comment: i did cleaning but still the problem persist

Comment: upgrade your sdk if not updated and then rebuild project

Comment: please see a screen shot posted above

Comment: @LetsamrIt have you tried restart Android Studio ??

Answer (score 0):

Update your Android SDK Manager Install all component of Android 6.0 (API 23)

Answer (score 0):

R file can be erased due to many reasons, try **rebuilding your project**(which is the most common issue) and other issues may include any syntax error or inappropriate file permissions in work space, the exact error report can help address the issue better.